# Percentage by column and group

Tags: microsoft-excel

I have a data like this

| country | Group | Number |
| --- | --- | --- |
| Spain | A | 1000 |
| Spain | B | 1500 |
| Spain | C | 1200 |
| Engand | A | 5000 |
| Engand | B | 500 |
| Engand | C | 2900 |
| Japan | A | 3000 |
| Japan | B | 1200 |
| Japan | C | 3000 |

I would like to create a new column with the percentage of each group by country, like this

| country | Group | Number | Percentage |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| Spain | A | 1000 | 11.11% |
| Spain | B | 1500 | 46.87% |
| Spain | C | 1200 | 16,90 |

my real worksheet is much bigger than this one, so I can't to calculate manually, I need a formula or other thing that select automatically all same group and calculate the percentage.

Comment: Did you try a pivot table with filters?

Answer (score 2):

If you don't want a pivot table, then you could use this SUMIFS formula, found in cell D2:

```
=C2/SUMIFS($C$2:$C$10,$A$2:$A$10,A2)
```

[image]

This divides the row amount by the grouped country sum. The sample data you provided and the desired output does not match this, so let me know if you're looking for something different. But I could not determine how you got those percentages based on your sample data.

**UPDATE**

Correcting it here, calculating by Group, not country:

```
=C2/SUMIFS($C$2:$C$10,$B$2:$B$10,B2)
```

[image]

Comment: change A2 to B2 to get the % presented in OP question